# How to make spring roo project has dynamic web nature?

Tags: eclipse, spring-roo, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

Hi I'm giving a try of Spring Roo, I have STS installed with eclipse.
if I do new-> Dynamic Web -> add spring roo nature, the spring roo shell keep showing message of "Not spring roo installed" (actually I have it installed in preference->spring roo)

if I do new->spring Roo project, the project generated is a java standard application and not a web application :S but the ROO console works 
and I do "controller all --package ~.web" command it only generate web.xml but still missing the option run as.. -> server

screenshot: http://i54.tinypic.com/14mqu8h.jpg

any idea?

Comment: Which STS/Roo version are you using?

Comment: Eclipse Helio, STS:2.6.1.RELEASE, Roo:1.1.4.RELEASE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please run the `perform eclipse` Roo command in your Roo Console on your project and see.

You should probably run your Roo project with m2eclipse addon installed. Use `tomcat:run` as your Maven goal.

There is a series of articles on the starting from the following link which would address most of your questions related to eclipse configuration.

http://blog.lckymn.com/2009/05/17/roo-so-cool-01/

Cheers!!!

Comment: I did perform eclipse, also did controller all --package ~.web, but still not  "run as->on server option" http://i54.tinypic.com/14mqu8h.jpg

Comment: Did you go through the article series in the link? :)

Comment: yea I did, I think my eclipse is broken. I just installed the STS (this time not as eclipse plugin) and it worked :S thank you!